# Unable to login with local user in machine(RHEL7) after LDAP integartion

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat

I am new with RedHat IDM. Below is my requirement. Please help.

Suppose that we have two machines of RHEL7:

1. Redhat IDM server
2. Redhat IDM client machine

Now we have created two users on IDM client machine with this process:

- Create the first user with a simple linux command

  > useradd ravendra
- The second user we create using this IPA command:

  > ipa user-add jsmith --first=John --last=Smith --manager=bjensen
  >   --email=johnls@example.com --homedir=/home/work/johns --password

Now we have this requirement:

1. If the IDM server is running then we want to restrict the ssh of user "ravendra" which is created through the normal linux command: Only "jsmith" can ssh to the IDM client machine
2. If the IDM server is stopped, then both users can ssh to the IDM client machine.

Can you recommend a plug-in and/or config I can use to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should rather be asked on serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

If you wish some custom auth, best / easiest way is to write custom pam module. Then use it with your ssh daemon, and do all the magic inside that module.

Actually there is not much about it at RHEL docs - [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/pluggable_authentication_modules) is the link. Quick search shows that there is [python module](http://pam-python.sourceforge.net/doc/html/) for that. I mean - you can do the module with python, which should much easier then C/C++.

Also if you wish to look for more information - there is [answer at serverfault](https://superuser.com/questions/792804/use-custom-ssh-authentication-mechanism-openssh) as Roidu spotted.